# changing 100 % from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

Around 6 months ago i installed ubuntu from a CD i burned from an internet download, with the intention of running it for while to see how i got on with it compared to XP. now i'm completely happy with it , in despair with the way XP has begun to "perform", i want to go the whole way. my problem is that when i first started the installation i was asked how much disk space i wanted to allocate,  i have 160 gb total, so i chose 50gb, or thereabouts, which has left round 85gb for windows plus around 15gb for "f" drive (i think it was created by the previous owner). i have kept ubuntu reasonably up to date, and currently have "saucy salamander" up and running, although i believe there may be a later version. i have backed up all my files on XP onto a portable hard drive ready for the big move. my question is how do i get windows back to 0 and increase ubuntu to the maximum gb available ? will i have to uninstall ubuntu completely, re-install it again and next time i'm asked about the disk space select 100%, or 160 gb, then simply go through the basics of re-installing any add-ons, then install any updates since my CD version (or would it be better to simply download the latest version and install from that?). or is there a "magic button/formula" somewhere that says give all the XP disk space over to Ubuntu and wipe XP for ever? 
 i am far from being a techy person, i'm only going to use ubuntu as a simple desktop for internet/email, some media playing and some libre office, so i'd appreciate any answers as simple as possible, thats to say idiot proof :-)

Answer (score 0):

Insert your "live" DVD-ROM or USB "thumb" drive and start the process to install Ubuntu, then select "Replace Windows 'x' with Ubuntu" during the setup (as per step four: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop ) and Ubuntu will do the rest... Just make sure you have everything backed-up first - this will wipe your computer beforehand!

There are ways to achieve this without wiping the computer first, but with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") becoming available yesterday/today/tomorrow (depending on where you live...), you're going to have a much cleaner and more efficient system after doing a complete, "clean" installation... A "clean" installation is also easier, and will ensure that your new Ubuntu 14.04 LTS ("Trusty Tahr") installation doesn't have any left-over "junk", which could slow things down or take-up valuable space.

Comment: many thanks for that, i think i understand most of it, maybe all ! to be on the safe side are you saying my best option is to download the latest version, 14.04LTS, burn onto a disc, then insert disc to start installation and when i get to the bit about whether to get rid of XP for ever say yes and simply continue ? will this also get rid of the old ubuntu or should i uninstall that as well ?

Comment: i should have said that time is not a problem with me, if it takes an hour, fine, if it takes all day, no worries.

Comment: Download the latest version of Ubuntu onto a DVD or USB "thumb" drive ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop )( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu )( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu ), insert the disk, reboot the computer and then select the apropriate option as per my original reply... You don't need to un-install anything - a "clean" installation of Ubuntu will wipe the computer completely, and install everything fresh.

Comment: Ah bugger, wrong links! Here's how to install Ubuntu ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop ), here's how to "burn" it to a DVD ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows ) and here's how to create a "thumb" drive ( http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows )... Let me know if you get stuck.